# Flask app showing Internal server error despite of setting debug = True

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jupyter-notebook, internal-server-error

While running my flask web app in **Jupyter Notebook**, the first problem I encountered was

```
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

then somewhere I saw that using `app.run(debug = True,use_reloader = False)` solves this problem! In my case it did solve it but now I'm facing another problem and that is I'm unable to get the error trace back despite of having `dubug = True`
Whenever I run my app it just shows ***"Internal Server app"***
I tried solutions mentioned before like **setting environment to development**

```
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

But it didn't work!

Can you tell me how to fix it??

Comment: Have you tried to run it with python script outside of jupyter?

Comment: Yup! The script worked perfectly fine when run from command prompt!